# how to create a correct make file with MQ C program

Tags: c

I have to create a makefile for a C program, which remotely connects to IBM MQ. what I have so far is

```
CC = /usr/bin/gcc    
MQM_HOME = /opt/mqm    
CFLAG = $(DEBUG) -O -q64 -qrtti=all\    
         -I$(MQM_HOME)/inc\    
         -I/usr/include    

IBM_LIBS= -liconv    

MQ_LIBPATH=-L$(MQM_HOME)/lib64    
MQLIB = $(MQ_LIBPATH) -lmqm -lmqmcs -l lmqmzse    

LIBS = $(IBM_LIBS) $MQLIB) -lpthreads    

SOURCE=/home/avalanche/xxxx    
EXE = $(SOURCE)/executable    
MAIN = $(SOURCE)/xxxx.c    
OBJ = $(SOURCE)/xxxx.o $(SOURCE)/xxxx.o $(SOURCE)/xxxx.o    

.SUFFIXS: .c .o    
#Compilation rules    
.c.o:    
      $(CC) $(CFLAG) -c -o ${<:.c=.o}  $<    

all:     $(OBJ) $(EXE)    
      @if [ -z "$(DEBUG)" ];\    
      then\    
           rm -f $(OBJ);\    
           rm -f ${MAIN:.c=.o};\    
      fi;    
      @echo "Done"    
$(EXE):  $(OBJ) ${MAIN:.c=.o}    
       rm -f $(OBJ)    
       rm -f ${MAIN:.c=.o}    

clean:    
   \rm -f $(OBJ)    
   \rm -f $(EXE)
```

The makefile doesn't understand 
    -q64 -qrtti=all
and some other errors. Could you please help me to make a correct makefile? I am on Linux, connect to MQ C program

Comment: Why don't you post error log ?

Comment: I mention that it doesn't recognize some command

Comment: Any specialist, who can help me with the makefile?